# Kotlin: How to write nested loops in functional way?

Tags: loops, kotlin, functional-programming

What could be an alternate way to print the cells of a table other than using a nested loop.

```
for(i in 1..2){
  for(j in 1..2){
      println("$i,$j")
  }
}
```

Any approach using Pairs?

Comment: Using pairs isn’t a better approach because then you’re instantiating a bunch of objects.

Comment: Yes you are right. Better isn't the right word here, I''ll change it to alternate :P. It's become habitual for me to consider _kotlin-ized_ code better, which is obviously not the case always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map/flatMap to convert the ranges to list of Pairs

```
val pairs = (1..2).flatMap { i -> (1..2).map { j -> i to j } }
pairs.forEach { println("${it.first},${it.second} ") }
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for